# Special case of pointwise convergence without uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Is it possible to find a sequence of uniformly bounded, continuous and increasing functions $f _n:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that they converge pointwise to a continuous function $f$ but the convergence is not uniform?

Thanks!

Comment: $f_n(x) = \chi_{(-\infty,n]}$ is a discontinuous example. The idea should be the same with continuous example. (and by increasing, do you mean $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ ?)

Comment: No, by increasing I mean $f_n(x)\leq f_n(y)$ whenever $x\leq y$ for all $n$. You are right, thanks!

Comment: Then $f_n(x) = \chi_{[-n,\infty)}(x)$ is a discontinuous example. To get a continuous one, just "connect" the jump at around $-n$

Answer (score 0):

No, this does not hold. Consider e.g. $$f_n(x) := \begin{cases} 0, & x \leq 0, \\ \left( \frac{x}{n} \right)^n, & x \in (0,n), \\ 1, & x \geq n. \end{cases}$$

Note however that the claim does hold true if the sequence is increasing in the sense that $f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (by [Dini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini's_theorem)).